# Antd Charts - Show only total value for column label for series data in Column Chart

Tags: antd

I have a `Column` chart that presents grouped data based on a property (using the `seriesField` property). Here is [the stacked Column chart](https://charts.ant.design/%7Edemos/column-demo-15) I am using from [Antd Columns Charts](https://charts.ant.design/demos/column) and [this is the docs](https://charts.ant.design/demos/column/?type=api) I'm using for reference.

My issue is that I can't find a way to show only the total value of the group for a label for the whole column instead of for each separate section (and this is a very basic feature). The docs are terrible - badly structured and half of the content is in chinese as well.

Has anyone stumbled upon this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to find [the solution](https://g2plot.antv.vision/en/examples/column/stacked#annotation-label) in another documentation. You can achieve the following by using the `annotations` property as specified in the example.

`annotations` reference in the docs: https://charts.ant.design/demos/column?type=api.